# Google Cast: Detect QueueItems that fail to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I have a Chrome sender application which uses a Styled Media Receiver to play a queued list of audio tracks.

To queue / autoplay items, I am creating a `QueueLoadRequest` up-front which contains a URL for each item in the list. At some point during playback (eg, a URL has expired), a track might fail to load.

I want to be able to detect this situation - where an item in a queue has failed to load, but I cannot find anything that does this succinctly.

For example, in the case where you are currently playing an audio track (*track 1*), and will soon automatically progress to *track 2*, which has a URL which will fail to load:

A listener registered with `Media.addUpdateListener()` will get called when *track 2* fails to load, but will simply report a `playerState` of *'Idle'*. The `idleReason` is perpetually given as *'Interrupted'*.

In order to determine there has been any kind of error at all, when an *'Idle'* state is found, you must make a call to `Media.getStatus()`. Within the success callback of this call, if you again check the `playerState`, it is still reported as *'Idle'*, but the reason is now given as *'Error'*. At this point we have to make a fairly large assumption that this has been caused by a media URL failing to load.

There must be a better way?

**Remote Debugger Logs**

When skipping to the failing track, the remote debugger logs show that the 401 occured and suggests that a `LOAD_FAILED` message was sent, but it never seems to materialise in the sender.

```
GET http://<REDACTED_URL_THAT_THROWS_A_401> 401 (Unauthorized)g.load @ cast_receiver.js:64X.tc @ cast_receiver.js:119Wc @ player.js:50Nc @ player.js:46Y.O @ player.js:40h.ta @ player.js:58id @ cast_receiver.js:118qd @ cast_receiver.js:126g.Cc @ cast_receiver.js:135X.sb @ cast_receiver.js:106R.tb @ cast_receiver.js:35Db @ cast_receiver.js:24g.dispatchEvent @ cast_receiver.js:23g.ub @ cast_receiver.js:33Db @ cast_receiver.js:24g.dispatchEvent @ cast_receiver.js:23g.ub @ cast_receiver.js:30
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.331s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error: [object Object]$b @ cast_receiver.js:40Yb.hc @ cast_receiver.js:40B.log @ cast_receiver.js:13J @ cast_receiver.js:14X.qb @ cast_receiver.js:123g.qb @ cast_receiver.js:61zb @ cast_receiver.js:20wb @ cast_receiver.js:21(anonymous function) @ cast_receiver.js:19
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.890s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"setappstate\",\"statusText\":\"Now Casting: <REDACTED_AUDIO_TITLE>\"}"}
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.918s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.924s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"","data":"{\"requestId\":0,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.934s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.940s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.945s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.950s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus: {"mediaSessionId":1,"sessionId":"5D841D2B-AB1E-4CD3-ACC9-B308A164E77C","requestId":70783069}
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.957s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 11:client-99231
cast_receiver.js:40  [ 50.964s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"11:client-99231","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"IDLE\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"https://<REDACTED_URL_THAT_THROWS_A_401>\",\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"contentType\":\"audio/mp3\",\"metadata\":{\"type\":3,\"metadataType\":3,\"title\":\"<REDACTED_AUDIO_TITLE>\",\"artist\":\"<REDACTED_ARTIST>\",\"trackNumber\":2,\"images\":[{\"url\":\"//<REDACTED_IMAGE_URL>\"}]}},\"currentItemId\":2,\"idleReason\":\"ERROR\"}],\"requestId\":70783069}"}
```

Comment: Could you post the logs from your receiver console when an item fails to load (make sure you enable logging first).

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I'm unable to get anything from the remote debugger. I can connect on port 9222 and follow the link to _Remote Debugging (AppEngine)_, which brings up the console, but I get no feedback. Nothing in the console, no elements and no network actions? No change after entering _cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);_ in the console

Comment: Do you click on the shield icon in box that you type url (toward the end of that box)? If not, do that and in the popup that shows up click on the button to give access and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some logs to the original post.

Comment: I see the issue. I will open an internal ticket to address that; we will probably change the behavior so that you would automatically get a status update broadcast with IDLE status with ERROR for the reason, and I imagine that would do what you want, correct?

Comment: Thanks, yes - it would be good to have the `idleReason=ERROR` reported without having to make the additional `getStatus` request. Even better would be to have a `playerState=ERROR` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, this has been raised as an issue against the Cast SDK.

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest SDK release: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes